# Android: How to get facebook user image using access_token

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on an application that need to `login with facebook`. This is the first time when i am integrating Fb API in my application. I have start from [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) & successfully get fb `access_token`. 
There are three `Activitie` in my application & what i need to manage is to have logged in user's Profile Image & name on all these `Activities` when user successfully get login using facebook.
I know, i can query fb [`GraphAPI`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) & get complete profile data of current logged-in user using access_token. I succeed to get profile data of user by using valid `access_token` using_
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?<access_token>&format=json`
 I need the profile image of login user as well(which need user's `fb_id`)
`http://graph.facebook.com/<fb_id>/picture?type=large`
**Is it possible to get user's profile image using `access_token`?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, after a long search, i got the way to access login user's image by using only `access_token`
    `https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token=<your_access_token_here>`
 thanks to @Jess for your valuable answer!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an access token to retrieve a user's profile image.  Just issue a http GET request on http://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_ID_HERE/picture, so for example:

http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture gets you user id 4's picture, no access token needed.

EDIT:

To fetch the picture without knowing their fb id but with their access token, just execute a GET request on `/me?fields=name,picture` and you will receive a response with the URL to their profile picture.

See Graph API Tool example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cpicture

Comment: Thanks @ Jesse for your valuable answer but i have already mentioned that we can get user`s profile image by using `fb_id` _ `http://graph.facebook.com/<fb_id>/picture?type=large`. what i need is, when user successfully get login using `fb` he get unique `access_token` & than if i want user image than again i have to request user`s data from graph api `https://graph.facebook.com/me?<access_token=your_valid_token>&format=json
` & get user`s `fb_id` from response. so is it not possible to directly get user`s image by using his `access_token` without requesting for his profile data?

Comment: Thanks Jesse! it works...:) It will give me the `url` that return me the profile image of facebook login user. Sorry but again it is not that which i am looking for. As this(`http://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_ID_HERE/picture`) will directly return me the profile image... can we get(profile image) by using `access_token` directly?

Comment: I guess the answer to your question is no, then.  As far as I know, there is no way to do one direct fetch of the profile picture given only the access token.  Although you may want to look at this link (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/games/personalize/#step2) which our Facebook SDK has a `ProfilePictureView` class that you can use which will handle the fetching of the profile picture.  Hope that helps.

Comment: as of today, you must pass access token along with picture field to get user profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

So after messing around with the facebook graph apis for a bit, I have found that you can get the profile pic in two ways:

1. Use this as the profile pic url by substituting the user id:
   https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?return_ssl_resources=1
2. Using the access token: 
   https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Hope this is helpful.