# How to provide automatic login to Facebook in android application if user once logged in ?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using graph api in my android application to connect to facebook.Now what i'm doing is creating an instance for my Facebook class and calling the login method from main activity each time.If user login one time using the application,and the next time when the user opens application,it should directly login using the previous active facebook session..How to do this ?Sombody please help...

Login button click method

```
public void onBtnClicked(View v){
            if(v.getId() == R.id.btnLogin)
            {

                FacebookClass na = new FacebookClass(this);
                na.login();
             }
}
```

This is my login method

```
public void login() 
{
    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(mContext, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
             if (session.isOpened()) {


                        sessionState = true;


                 Toast.makeText(mContext, "Access token :" + session.getAccessToken() + "\n" +"Expires at "+session.getExpirationDate().toLocaleString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                      Log.i("sessionToken", session.getAccessToken());
                      Log.i("sessionTokenDueDate", session.getExpirationDate().toLocaleString());

                     access_token =session.getAccessToken();

                     pref = mContext.getPreferences(0);
                     edt = pref.edit();

                      Editor prefsEditor = pref.edit();
                      edt.putString("Access token", access_token);
                      edt.commit();

                /**
                 * getting user's name and location
                 */

                 // make request to the /me API
                  Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                         if (user != null)
                         {
                              dispname = user.getName();
                              id = user.getId();

                              Object userLocation = user.getLocation();

                              Log.i("Profile information", ""+response);

                             String strLocation = (userLocation != null)? ((GraphObject) userLocation).getProperty("name").toString() : "No location found";


                                //location.setText("Lives in " + strLocation + "!");

                               disploc = strLocation;

                               edt.putString("Username", dispname);
                               edt.putString("Location", disploc);
                               edt.commit();

                           ((MainActivity)mContext).dispatchInformations(dispname,disploc);


                              }
                    }
                  }).executeAsync();



                  /**
                   * Getting user's profile picture
                   */
                  Bundle params = new Bundle();
                  params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
                  params.putString("type", "normal");
                  params.putString("height", "200");
                  params.putString("width", "200");
                  new Request(
                          Session.getActiveSession(),
                            "/me/picture",
                            params,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new Request.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    /* handle the result */
                                    Log.i("Profile pic", ""+response);
                                    GraphObject graph=response.getGraphObject();
                                    JSONObject jsonObj=graph.getInnerJSONObject();
                                    JSONObject object;
                                    String imageURL;



                                    try {
                                         object = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
                                          imageURL=object.getString("url");

                                          new DownloadImageTask().execute(imageURL);


                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        ).executeAsync();

             }





}

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset,
            Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

 }

 });

}
```

Comment: on first time login, set in sharedpref. and then check when you come again if sharedpref values is available. if yes then perform login of facebook with that values..

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `Session.getActiveSession();`

**For example** Use this inside `onCompleted()` method

```
Session facebooksession = Session.getActiveSession();
if(facebooksession != null) {
//Second time login
}
else{
//First time login
}
```

Comment: i'm getting null always :( but its logged in...how to fix this ?is there anything related to onActivityResult ??please help

Comment: @Nevaeh You added my code inside `onCompleted()` method? if user logged in first time through your app then it will be null if same user logs in to app second time then it will not be null

Comment: I will explain.I have a class for facebook login and getting details.I have written the onActivityResult method in my main activity.The first code snippet in question is from my main activity and second is from my facebook class.so,my problem is,i want to check whether there is any active session when app is launched.if yes,then i want to display the name and picture automatically in my left menu.else,i want to display a login button.I hope u understood what i told.please reply

Comment: Then you need to use SharedPreference, In the SharedPreference u need to save image and name. If Data exists in SharedPreference then show the result else move to login

Comment: I'm saving access token in sharedPreferences.can i use that ?

Comment: Yes you can get Image and Name from AccessToken. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14002212/2811956)

Comment: i did that using access token.thanks for the reply :)